# pyjnius not working in virtual environment

Tags: python, django, pyjnius

I am working with pyjnius in django. I am not able to import it as a module so i am using it like this

```
os.system("python  home/pyjnius/jnius/run_me.py " + path)
```

that works normally but in virtual environment it gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run_me.py", line 11, in <module>
from jnius import autoclass
ImportError: No module named jnius
```

[this](https://www.hackzine.org/using-apache-tika-from-python-with-jnius.html) is the code i am follwing

please can anyone point some direction here as how to use pyjnius in virtual environment or where i am making mistakes.

in run_me.py this is the [code](https://www.hackzine.org/using-apache-tika-from-python-with-jnius.html)

```
import os
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/'
os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = "/path/to/tika-app.jar"

from jnius import autoclass

## Import the Java classes we are going to need
Tika = autoclass('org.apache.tika.Tika')
Metadata = autoclass('org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata')
FileInputStream = autoclass('java.io.FileInputStream')

tika = Tika()
meta = Metadata()
text = tika.parseToString(FileInputStream(filename), meta)
```

thankyou

Comment: What's inside run_me.py file? Why you cannot import pyjnius as a module?

Comment: i have made the changes above for run_me.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had some trouble getting this to work as well.

The following worked for me:

Create a new virtualenv, just in case, and activate it.

```
# install pyjnius
pip install cython
cd [virtualenv]/src/
git clone https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius.git
cd pyjnius
python setup.py install

# get the tika-app (don't know if this is the latest version)
wget http://apache.proserve.nl/tika/tika-app-1.5.jar
mv tika-app-1.5.jar /usr/local/lib/

# put the following in .bashrc
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/lib/tika-app-1.5.jar
```

Comment: Thank you that  worked  i am using os.system(..) can you please show some way to import jnius as python module from /virtualenv/src/

Comment: do you want to import `run_me` or `jnius`?

Comment: `jnius`  if i could import it i would write run_me.py code in django's view

Comment: Hmm, I'm using it in a management command.
The issue occurs when tika is not available on the `CLASSPATH`. Maybe the `os.environ['CLASSPATH']` should happen earlier in the request chain.